# "Access denied" when trying to create a new application on WSS (Sharepoint) 3.0 SP2

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

I installed WSS SP2 on my Windows 7 (bamboo option). I can log into administratiion site but when I try to create a new application I got the error: "Access denied".

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. Try to run IE with administrator rights (select in context menu "Run as administrator"), for me it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations always turn off UAC (User Account Control).